# Git clone from private github repository with Github Actions token

Tags: github-actions, git-clone

I need to do some directory grooming before my app is ready to be tested or deployed. I would like to utilize a Makefile target which calls a shell script in the repo to make this CI/CD-agnostic. One can call this target with `make prepare_directory`

The CI platform I am using is Github Actions. Here are the relevant parts of the workflow which is being run on new Pull Requests:

```
name: PR Tests
env:
  GIT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 1
      - name: Prep directoy
        run: make prepare_directory
```

Here is the relevant part of the Makefile (which works exactly as expected locally):

```
...
prepare_directory:
    ./scripts/prepare_directory.sh

clean:
    @rm -Rf ./$(BUILDPREFIX)

.PHONY: all clean docker lint prep_avro $(dockerbuilds)
```

Here is the relevant part of the `./scripts/prepare-directory.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# ...
# clone repo using https and GITHUB_TOKEN
git clone https://$GIT_TOKEN@github.com:USERNAME/REPO.git
```

When I try to clone using that URL, from the shell script, the script fails (along with the Github workflow pipeline) with the following error: `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com:USERNAME/REPO.git/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've created a GitHub App and Github Action to workaround these limitations [GitHub Actions Access Manager](https://github.com/qoomon/github-actions-access-manager). Feel free to drop some feedback.

#### Workflow

[image]

1. This GitHub action will request an access token for a **Target Repository** from the **App Server**, authorize by the GitHub Action ID Token (JWT signed by GitHub).
2. The App Server requests a **GitHub App Installation Token** to read `.github/access.yaml` file in **Target Repository**.
3. The App Server reads `.github/access.yaml` file from **Target Repository** and determine which permissions should be granted to **Requesting Repository**, authorized by the **GitHub App Installation Token** from step `2.`.
4. The App Server requests a **GitHub App Installation Token** with granted permissions for **Source Directory** and send it back in response to the GitHub action from step `1.`.
5. The GitHub action sets the token as environment variable `$GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` and as step output value `${{ steps.github-actions-access.outputs.token }}`.
6. Further steps can then utilize this token to access resources of the **Target Repository**.

Answer (score 1):

The URL in your `prepare-directory.sh` script's `git clone` call has a typo in it:

```
# clone repo using https and GITHUB_TOKEN
git clone https://$GIT_TOKEN@github.com:USERNAME/REPO.git
```

The URL there is halfway between an HTTPS git URL and an SSH one. The `:` should be a `/`. Assuming your `$GIT_TOKEN` contains just the token and nothing else, you'd also need a `:` before the `@`:

```
git clone https://$GIT_TOKEN:@github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git
```

If your `$GIT_TOKEN` contained the complete auth string, which for a Github App installation access token would be something like `"x-access-token:ghs_..."` then you wouldn't need the `:` following `$GIT_TOKEN`, you'd just have `$GIT_TOKEN@github.com`.

Comment: Good catch on the bad URL format. The syntax in your post with the colon following $GIT_TOKEN didn't work for me. We know from his workflow that $GIT_TOKEN doesn't already include x-access-token because we can see how $GIT_TOKEN is set, so we have to add `x-access-token:` before `$GIT_TOKEN`. Also I don't see why he's using an env var; that just complicates things to no benefit. It should just be `git clone https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this [action](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent) after your checkout step and GitHub can access your private repo dependancy.

Note:- Make sure to add a server's private key as a secret, public key to GitHub SSH keys and Please replace your private repo URL from https+auth_token to SSH. ssh://git@github.com/your_group/your_project.git

Below is the example

```yaml
      - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.4.1
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
```

`SSH_KEY` is the private key secret which you created.